# Puppet permissions issue reported on client

Tags: puppet

`err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call search on /file_metadata/plugins with {:ignore=>[".svn", "CVS", ".git"], :recurse=>true, :checksum_type=>"md5", :links=>"manage"}`

`err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/plugins Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://example.com/plugins: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/plugins`

What exactly causes this error, and how to fix it? Or how to debug?

Comment: Just in case it helps someone in the future: I had the same problem, and for me it was due to the version of puppet on the master being behind the version on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this out, it was missing permissions from the fileserver.conf file:

Changing the contents of this file to:

```
[plugins]
  allow *.com
```

And restarting puppetmaster fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me downgrading facter package on the client fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get puppet agent 3.6 to work with an older puppet 2.7 server @andoni's answer is correct.

This is what I had to do on CentOS 7.

```
yum install -y puppet
rpm -e facter --nodeps
gem install facter -v 1.7.6
```